# Will Django user permissions work for models with inline tabular forms of other models?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am setting up DJango admin to make a model editable.  On the same page I have tabular inline of a child model.  Everything works as expected.  Now I want to restrict permission on the tabular inline child form. Specifically remove update and delete permissions on it. I have tried removing the permissions for the admin user using the 'user permissions' of that user.  However, it does not work.  Does DJango respect the user permissions in regards to inline model forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as of django 1.4. Here's the original ticket: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8060